# SQL select results not appearing if a value is null

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am building a complex select statement, and when one of my values (pcf_auto_key) is null it will not disipaly any values for that header entry.

```
select c.company_name, h.prj_number, h.description, s.status_code, h.header_notes, h.cm_udf_001, h.cm_udf_002, h.cm_udf_008, l.classification_code
from project_header h, companies c, project_status s, project_classification l
where exists 
  (select company_name from companies where h.cmp_auto_key = c.cmp_auto_key)
  and exists
  (select status_code from project_status s where s.pjs_auto_key = h.pjs_auto_key)
  and exists
  (select classification_code from project_classification where h.pcf_auto_key = l.pcf_auto_key)
  and pjm_auto_key = 11
  --and pjt_auto_key = 10
  and c.cmp_auto_key = h.cmp_auto_key
  and h.pjs_auto_key = s.pjs_auto_key
  and l.pcf_auto_key = h.pcf_auto_key
  and s.status_type = 'O'
```

How does my select statement look? Is this an appropriate way of pulling info from other tables?

This is an oracle database, and I am using SQL Developer.

Comment: Look at how Oracle handles nulls, [particularly with comparison conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF30037). You should also consider using explicit `join` syntax, which will make it easier to use outer joins, which you may require here - not sure it's clear what you want to happen though. Table structures, sample data and expected results would be helpful. What are the `exists` clauses supposed to be doing - your have those as (implicit) join conditions already?

Comment: use joint man!!! plus a WHERE clause. from what i understand you want your top result set only if other values exists which is exactly what an inner join does

Comment: Thank you guys. looks like I need to be using joins.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to show all the data that you can find but display the `classification` as blank when there is no match in that table, you can use a left outer join; which is much clearer with explicit join syntax:

```
select c.company_name, h.prj_number, h.description, s.status_code,  h.header_notes,
  h.cm_udf_001, h.cm_udf_002, h.cm_udf_008, l.classification_code
from project_header h
join companies c on c.cmp_auto_key = h.cmp_auto_key
join project_status s on s.pjs_auto_key = h.pjs_auto_key
left join project_classification l on l.pcf_auto_key = h.pcf_auto_key
where pjm_auto_key = 11
and s.status_type = 'O'
```

I've taken out the `exists` conditions as they just seem to be replicating the join conditions.

If you might not have matching data in any of the other tables you can make the other inner joins into outer joins in the same way, but be aware that if you outer join to `project_status` you will need to move the `statatus_type` check into the join condition as well, or Oracle will convert that back into an inner join.

[Read more about the different kinds of joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries006.htm#SQLRF30046).

Comment: Thanks man! I guess I need to be using joins and left joins. I don't even know what a left join is so I need to do some reading. Cheers,